# How can I quickly delete the trailing pathname component in ido-mode?

Tags: key-bindings, ido

I use `ido-mode` for finding files and directories, which is generally very efficient in terms of keystrokes.

The one annoyance I've found is when deleting the trailing pathname component when using `ido-find-file`.  E.g., if the minibuffer contains `/some/long/directory/path/and.some.long.file.name`, I would like to quickly delete `and.some.long.file.name` with a single keystroke.  It seems hard to believe that this isn't built-in, but if so I haven't found the keybinding for it.

Is there a quick way to erase the trailing file name, or another efficient way of dealing with this?

Comment: There probably is, and an Ido user will no doubt help you with a good answer. I tried looking in the Ido manual. It's a mess, IMHO. The index is pretty much useless. If I were an Ido user I would ask for an improvement. As an Emacs user, I at least filed a [bug report](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18691) just now suggesting that the index be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a built-in way to do that (well `M-^ C-k` seems to work, but that's a little bit hacky). That said, implementing it doesn't look too difficult. I believe the following would do:

```
(defun ido-clear-fname ()
  (interactive)
  (setq ido-text-init ""
        ido-exit 'refresh)
  (exit-minibuffer))

(define-key ido-common-completion-map (kbd "<C-M-backspace>") 'ido-clear-fname)
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was hoping for, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`M-backspace` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>) is quite efficient.  It'll kill whole words instead of single characters.  It's perhaps not a single key solution in your case, but you can use it pretty much everywhere in Emacs or in shell.

Answer (score 0):

I found in my `.emacs` the following function which does work as expected:

```
(defun kill-back-to-indentation ()
  "Kill from point back to the first non-whitespace character on the line."
  (interactive)
  (let ((prev-pos (point)))
    (back-to-indentation)
    (kill-region (point) prev-pos)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-<backspace>") 'kill-back-to-indentation)
```

Yes, this function is not ido-specific but rather for general purposes.

Comment: You can also just use this as the function body: `(kill-region (point) (progn (back-to-indentation) (point)))`.

Comment: Be warned that `C-M-<backspace>` may log you out of your Linux session with no warning.

Comment: @nispio which distros do you mean?

Comment: I put the warning in because it happened to me, and took me totally by surprise.  After a little research, it looks like `Ctrl+Alt+BackSpace` is often the default binding for "Kill X-Window Session."  But since X is going away, newer distros may not have a similar binding. Just like all things Linux, YMMV. I am using GNOME desktop on RHEL 6.5, and that is the default setting.